# change Bangla font style systemwide

Tags: kubuntu, fonts, tweak

[image]

This is a screenshot of my bangla font in Akregator in KUBUNTU 18.04. I don't know which font family for bangla is being used in my system. This font is seems ugly and unreadable. I am using English(us) as my system font. Here is a screenshot of my font setting.

[image]

This [method](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-change-the-default-font-of-a-specific-language-in-Linux-mint-18) results only a part but not on whole system.
[image]

How can I change **only the bangla font** style system-wide?

`fc-match -a | grep -iE 'bang|beng'` gives this:

```
userName@User:~$ fc-match -a | grep -iE 'bang|beng'
Lohit-Bengali.ttf: "Lohit Bengali" "Regular"
NotoSansBengali-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Bengali" "Regular"
NotoSansBengaliUI-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans Bengali UI" "Regular"
NotoSerifBengali-Regular.ttf: "Noto Serif Bengali" "Regular"
NotoSansBengali-Bold.ttf: "Noto Sans Bengali" "Bold"
NotoSansBengaliUI-Bold.ttf: "Noto Sans Bengali UI" "Bold"
NotoSerifBengali-Bold.ttf: "Noto Serif Bengali" "Bold"
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of this command: `fc-match -a | grep -iE 'bang|beng'`

Comment: You may want to try to uninstall the `fonts-lohit-beng-bengali` package. If you do, please note that a bunch of other fonts packages will be removed as well, but the Noto ones will stay.